# Can I split doublets to get home in parcheesi?

Tags: parcheesi

Can I split a doublets to get a man home? If I have two men out, throw double 4s, can I go 8 to get home and 6 with other man?

Answer (score 2):

> If I have two men out, throw double 4s, can I go 8 to get home and 6 with other man?

Yes.

When you roll doubles, it's as if you have four dice (instead of two) to use. In your example, rolling double 4 results in getting 3-3-4-4 as your options. You are allowed to split them however you wish, so your proposal to move one piece (to home) with 4+4 and the other piece with 3+3 is legal.